# Estimating angles from sine and cosine without losing sign information

Tags: trigonometry

I have two unknown angles: $\phi$ and $\theta$. I only have the information of $\mu$ and $\nu$, defined as $\mu = \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$ and $\nu = \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$. I want to estimate $\phi.$ I tried using the expression, $\phi_{est} =\arcsin(\sqrt{\mu^2+\nu^2}).$

However, doing so, the sign information is lost. For example, any positive negative combination of $\mu, \nu$ give me the same $\phi$. Is there any way to estimate $\phi$, preserving the sign information?

Comment: You seem not to have enough information to determine the sign of $\sin(\phi)$.  You can narrow $\theta$ down a little, but that seems to be about it.  Can you give some context for where this comes from?  Or if there are any other constraints that might help to simplify things?

Answer (score 1):

Might seem trivial but have you tried dividing $\nu$ and $\mu$?
From my understanding of the problem this should lead to

$$ \frac{\nu}{\mu} = \frac{\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)} = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} = \tan(\theta)$$

Now, are you allowed to use a calculator to compute $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{\nu}{\mu})$? If you are, well just compute the first angle and then substitute into either one of the expressions the get $\phi$. If by "estimate" you mean you are not allowed to use any inverse trig function, I suggest expading the tangent into its Taylor series

$$ \tan(x) = x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^4) $$

Be aware of the fact that this approximation works only in $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$